# Ask questions again if particular intent is triggered by the user

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I am trying to build a chatbot which mainly comprises of 2 tasks: Task 1. Ask users to share their pincode and choose the category. Fetch results using these two inputs and display the message. Task 2. 1. After the flow ends - If a user says “corona help“ - prompt him asking if he wants to get them for the above given pincode if not - give him a provision to input a new pincode.

Follow similar flow for category as well. For example ( let us say user asked for - Free Food in 600036 )

User : corona help Bot : Do you want to get the resources for - 600036. Press yes to confirm and no to change another pincode User : no Bot: Please share the pincode User : 500081 Bot : Do you want to get “ Free Food” . Press yes to confirm and no to change User : Yes Bot : Show results for 500081 and Free Food

I have already done with task 1 but having difficulty with task 2. I want to know how to ask questions and fill the required slots if a particular intent is triggered.

Here’s my rules.yml:

```
version: "2.0"

rules:

- rule: trigger corona help
  steps:
  - intent: corona_help
  - action: action_check_user_intent

- rule: Activate form
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: user_details_form
  - active_loop: user_details_form

- rule: Submit form
  condition:
  # Condition that form is active.
  - active_loop: user_details_form
  steps:
  # Form is deactivated
  - action: user_details_form
  - active_loop: null
  - slot_was_set:
    - requested_slot: null
  # The actions we want to run when the form is submitted.
  - action: action_submit
```

Actions.py:

```
class ValidateUserDetailsForm(FormValidationAction):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "validate_user_details_form"
    
    def validate_pin_code(self,
        slot_value: Any,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: DomainDict,
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:

        print("HERE1")
        url = f"https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/{slot_value}"
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(r.content)
        status = data[0]['Status']
        print(status)

        if status == 'Error':
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="Invalid PIN code. Enter again.")
            return {"pin_code": None}
        else:
            return {"pin_code": slot_value}

class ActionCheckUserIntent(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_check_user_intent"

    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: "DomainDict",
    ) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        intent = tracker.latest_message['intent'].get('name')
        print(intent)
        pin_code = tracker.get_slot("pin_code")
        print(pin_code)
        category = tracker.get_slot("category")

        if intent == "corona_help":
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_ask_confirm_pin_code")
            return {"confirm_pin_code": None, "confirm_category": None}

class ActionSubmit(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_submit"

    def run(
        self,
        dispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: "DomainDict",
    ) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        pin_code = tracker.get_slot("pin_code")
        category = tracker.get_slot("category")
        print("HERE2")
        pin_code_url = f"https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/{pin_code}"
        r1 = requests.get(pin_code_url)
        data1 = json.loads(r1.content)
        city = data1[0]['PostOffice'][0]['District']
        print("HERE3")
        city_url = "http://ec2-3-23-130-174.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/cities"
        r2 = requests.get(city_url)
        data2 = json.loads(r2.content)
        cities = data2['data']

        if city in cities:
            city = city.replace(" ", "%20")
            category = category.replace(" ", "%20")
            print("HERE4")
            category_url = f"http://ec2-3-23-130-174.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/resource?city={city}&category={category}"
            r = requests.get(category_url)
            data = json.loads(r.content)
            data = data['data']
            print(data)

            if not data:
                print("HERE5")
                dispatcher.utter_message(text="No resources found.")
                return []
                # return [AllSlotsReset()]

            contact = data[0]["contact"]
            description = data[0]["description"]
            organisation = data[0]["organisation"]
            phone = data[0]["phone"]
            state = data[0]["state"]

            category = category.replace("%20", " ")

            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_submit",
                                    pin_code=pin_code,
                                    category=category,
                                    contact = contact,
                                    description = description,
                                    organisation = organisation,
                                    phone = phone,
                                    state = state
                                    )
            # return [AllSlotsReset()]

        # elif intent == "corona_help":

        
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(text="No resources found.")
            # return [AllSlotsReset()]
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You might be better off asking this kind of question in the forum [here](https://forum.rasa.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the pin is most of your `user_details_form`. If so, one way to handle this would be to restart the user_details_form:

```
 - rule: corona help with previous pin code
  steps:
    - intent: corona_help
    - action: utter_ask_confirm_pin_code
    - intent: affirm # they want to use previous code
    - action: do_the_thing_with_old_pin_code

 - rule: corona help with new pin code
  steps:
    - intent: corona_help
    - action: utter_ask_confirm_pin_code
    - intent: deny # they don't want to use previous code
    - action: user_details_form
    - active_loop: user_details_form
```

You'll probably need to override `required_slots` for your form to make sure that the right slot is being re-asked, you can read more about that [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/forms/#dynamic-form-behavior).